# Links in accounts in profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, multiple-accounts

Currently users can see all of their accounts and reputations in any Stack Exchange site. While the site names are links to the profile in that very site, the reputations are only labels.

I suggest making the reputations links too. That would be very convenient.

Comment: I honestly can't see what benefit is added by making the reputation scores links as well. Why would it be "very convenient"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) in the ["Profile" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/217104/superm?tt=profile) of your profile page reputation is a link too :)

> [image]

<sup>But not in the "Activity" tab.</sup>